# Sinatra - Twilio schema validation warning

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I am receiving a schema validation warming in Twilio whenever I receive a text message to my Sinatra app. What could be causing this?

```
post '/receive_sms' do

content_type 'text/xml'

@time   = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
@body   = params["Body"].to_s
@sid    = params["MessageSid"].to_s
@sender = params["From"].delete('+')

puts @time
puts @body
puts @sender
puts @sid

CSV.open("/home/ubuntu/Applications/Twilio_SMS/smsLog.csv", "a") do |csv|
  csv << [@sid, @sender, @body, @time]
end

'done'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is because you are returning `"done"` as the response. Twilio expects to receive [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) (a subset of XML) as instructions with what to do in response to the SMS. In your case, I'm assuming you do not want to send a reply to the message, so you can just respond with an empty `<Response>` tag, like so:

```
post '/receive_sms' do
  content_type 'text/xml'

  @time   = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  @body   = params["Body"].to_s
  @sid    = params["MessageSid"].to_s
  @sender = params["From"].delete('+')

  puts @time
  puts @body
  puts @sender
  puts @sid

  CSV.open("/home/ubuntu/Applications/Twilio_SMS/smsLog.csv", "a") do |csv|
    csv << [@sid, @sender, @body, @time]
  end

  "<Response/>"
end
```